# Very simple library system with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am following the Odin Project and building the [Library project](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/javascript/lessons/library).

It is very simple, just render a list of Books and we can add and delete books from the list.

However, I feel the code can be improved hugely, as it is getting too messy and I am not sure if I am using the class in the right way.

This is the JavaScript:

```
const BOOKS_URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benoitvallon/100-best-books/master/';
const form = document.querySelector('#library-form');
const newBookBtn = document.querySelector('#new-book');
const library = [];

class Book {
  constructor({
    author,
    title,
    pages,
    imageLink,
    read = false,
  }) {
    this.readSatusBtn = null;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.imageLink = imageLink;
    this.read = !!read;
  }

  render(index) {
    const bookContainer = document.createElement('div');
    bookContainer.id = index;
    Object.keys(this).forEach((key) => {
      const data = document.createElement('div');
      data.innerText = this[key];
      bookContainer.appendChild(data);
    });
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'Delete';
    deleteBtn.class = 'delete-book';
    bookContainer.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    return bookContainer;
  }
}

let deleteBook;

function render() {
  const libraryContainer = document.querySelector('#library');
  const libContainer = document.createElement('div');
  libContainer.id = 'library';
  library.forEach((book, index) => {
    const bookElement = book.render(index);
    libContainer.appendChild(bookElement);
  });
  document.body.replaceChild(libContainer, libraryContainer);
  libContainer.addEventListener('click', deleteBook);
}

deleteBook = (event) => {
  if (event.target.class === 'delete-book') {
    const index = event.target.parentElement.id;
    library.splice(index, 1);
    render();
  }
};

function addBookToLibrary(book) {
  library.push(new Book(book));
  render();
}

function cleanFields() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach((input) => {
    input.value = '';
  });
}

function bringUpForm() {
  cleanFields();
  form.classList.add('active');
}

function processBook(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const book = {};
  const fd = new FormData(form);
  Array.from(fd).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    book[key] = value;
  });
  addBookToLibrary(book);
  form.classList.remove('active');
}

form.addEventListener('submit', processBook);
newBookBtn.addEventListener('click', bringUpForm);

fetch(`${BOOKS_URL}/books.json`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.slice(0, 4).forEach((book) => {
      book.imageLink = `${BOOKS_URL}/static/${book.imageLink}`;
      addBookToLibrary(book);
    });
  });
```

The `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Library</h1>
    <div id="library"></div>
    <button id="new-book">New Book</button>
    <form id="library-form">
      <div>
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="imageLink">Image url</label>
        <input id="imageLink" name="imageLink" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="pages">pages</label>
        <input id="pages" name="pages" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="read">Read</label>
        <input id="read" name="read" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the `css/index.css`:

```
#library-form {
    display: none;
  }

  #library-form.active {
    display: block;
  }
```

Thanks for any suggestions on how to improve this!